# Flask: Query Parameters and Method being Concatenated

Tags: python, flask, redirect

I am currently attempting to write a Flask redirect to run after submitting a form, but something's wrong with the Method that's being sent.  Instead of simply sending a GET or POST request, the method is concatenated with query parameters of the request form.  Instead of GET, it is sending `firstName=Tiny&lastName=Tim&pfp=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.thefamouspeople.com%2Fprofiles%2Fimages%2Ftiny-tim-2.jpg&SubmitUser=SubmitGET"`.  I've worked with redirects after form submissions before, but it would always call a redirect with a GET request without issue.  Adding this string as a method to the Flask route I'm trying to redirect to does let the redirect run properly, but needless to say that's not a feasible solution.  Does anyone know why this is happening?

Here's the form that is being sent:

```
        <form method="POST" action="/users/new/submit">
            <p><label id="lblFirstName">First Name: 
                <input type="text" id="inpFirstName" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name...">
            </label></p>
            <p><label id="lblLastName">Last Name: 
                <input type="text" id="inpLastName" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name...">
            </label></p>
            <p><label id="lblPfp">Profile Picture: 
                <input type="text" id="inpPfp" name="pfp" placeholder="Profile Picture Link...">
            </label></p>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

And here are my Flask routes.

```
@app.route('/users',methods=["GET","POST"])
def show_users():
    #Get links and records of all users.
    #Pass info into html.
    users = Users.query.all()
    return render_template('users.html',all_users=users)

@app.route('/users/new',methods=["GET"])
def add_user():
        return render_template('user_form.html')
 
@app.route('/users/new/submit',methods=["POST"])
def submit_user():
    #Will contain code that adds new user to database.
    return redirect('/users')
```

This is what comes up in my terminal:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2022 21:41:00] "GET /users/new HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2022 21:41:00] "GET /static/app.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2022 21:41:04] "POST /users/new/submit HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/Jun/2022 21:41:04] "firstName=Tiny&lastName=Tim&pfp=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.thefamouspeople.com%2Fprofiles%2Fimages%2Ftiny-tim-2.jpgGET /users HTTP/1.1" 405 -
```

Comment: There's something going on in code that youre not showing that's likely the culprit. Please post scaled-down versions of `show_users` and `submit_user` that still exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Just found out what was going wrong.  In the ```submit_user``` function, I didn't have any code beyond the Redirect because I just wanted to test the route flow.  Turns out because I didn't do anything with the form I submitted, Flask retained the form information when it was running the Redirect.  Doing anything with the form will clear out the payload and avoid this error.  Even ```print(request.form)``` will work.